# how to get rotation of laser-controls component inside A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I cannot get the rotation from the laser-controls component. I tried the following code:

```
this.laser.components['laser-controls'].el.object3D.getWorldRotation()
```

My entity looks like that

```
<a-entity laser-controls="hand: left></a-entity>
<a-entity laser-controls="hand: right></a-entity>
```

Btw, `this.laser` is the right hand entity.
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Make sure that you access the right laser-controls controller when using single controllers like Gear VR! In my case the right controller was `document.querySelectorAll('.laser-controls')[1]` and not `document.querySelectorAll('.laser-controls')[1][0]` ! Otherwise there is no rotation info with the non-existing controller.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: It is fixed, I try to access controller rotation information of a controller which does not exist, since Gear VR just has one controller.